# creating a 404 page with react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

Ok so I am working on making a 404 page for react but I don't know how to implement it properly this is what my code looks like

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <main className={`app ${isDark ? 'app--dark' : ''}`}>
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/conversations"
        component={() => (
          <Home colorMode={isDark} toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode} />
        )}
      />

      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/devnotes" component={Devnotes} />
      <ProtectedRoute path="/userinfo" component={UserInfo} />
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/settings"
        component={() => (
          <Setting colorMode={isDark} toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode} />
        )}
      />
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/developerhub"
        component={() => (
          <Developerhub
            className="devhub"
            colorMode={isDark}
            toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode}
          />
        )}
      />

      <Redirect to="/conversations" />

      <Route path="*">
        <FourOhFour />
      </Route>
    </main>
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

I watched quite a bit of youtube videos on how to do it and they all said for the path to be *, which is fine but I also don't want the 404 page showing up on all pages I just want it to show up on the ones that don't exist. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `main` element is between the `Switch` that ***exclusively*** matches and renders `Route` components and the `Route` components that are now ***inclusively*** matched and rendered because they aren't directly rendered by a `Switch`.

Move the `Switch` component *into* the `main` element. Also, don't use the `component` prop if rendering a component via a function, use the `render` prop function so the routed components are remounted when this parent component rerenders. Remove the `Redirect` unless you have a specific path you want to redirect from as it's currently redirecting any path not already matched above in the `Switch` and you won't hit the 404 path.

```
<Router>
  <main className={`app ${isDark ? "app--dark" : ""}`}>
    <Switch>
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/conversations"
        render={() => (
          <Home
            colorMode={isDark}
            toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode}
          />
        )}
      />

      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
      <Route path="/devnotes" component={Devnotes}/>
      <ProtectedRoute path="/userinfo" component={UserInfo}/>
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/settings"
        render={() => (
          <Setting colorMode={isDark} toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode}/>
        )}
      />
      <ProtectedRoute
        path="/developerhub"
        render={() => (
          <Developerhub
            className='devhub'
            colorMode={isDark}
            toggleColorMode={toggleColorMode}
          />
        )}
      />
      // <Redirect to="/conversations"/> remove this as it will block the 404 route below
        
      <Route path='*'> 
        <FourOhFour /> 
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </main>
</Router>
```